# Scan image borderless with scanimage, pnmtops, ps2pdf

Tags: printing, scanner, sane

I am scanning pages on my DIN A4 Scanner directly from command line.
How to I get rid of unwanted borders (or what am I doing wrong, such that I am getting them).

(Printer is a Epson ET-2750, bought in an „A4 paper format counry“ (Germany), and scanning full page borderless is not a problem in normal manual ways, i.e. using `simplescan`.)

A4 [has a size of](https://www.din-formate.de/tabelle-papierformate-seitengroesse-din-a-masse-umrechnungstabelle-in-inch-zoll-fuss-ft-yard-yd-millimeter-mm.html) 210×297 millimetres == 28.2677 × 11.6929 inch

This is my script (other than the border issue nicely working for quite some time):

```bash
scanimage -p --resolution 300 --mode Color --format=pnm -x 210 -y 297 \
| pnmtops -imageheight 11.41 -imagewidth 8.267 -height 11.41 -width 8.267  -setpage   \
| ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook - "$fname"
```

To figure out, where things get wrong, I outputted each of the 3 piped processes separately:

```bash
scanimage -p --resolution 300 --mode Color --format=pnm -x 210 -y 297  > step1.pnm

scanimage -p --resolution 300 --mode Color --format=pnm -x 210 -y 297 \
| pnmtops -imageheight 11.41 -imagewidth 8.267 -height 11.41 -width 8.267  -setpage   > step2.ps

scanimage -p --resolution 300 --mode Color --format=pnm -x 210 -y 297 \
| pnmtops -imageheight 11.41 -imagewidth 8.267 -height 11.41 -width 8.267  -setpage   \
| ps2pdf -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook - "step3.pdf"
```

[image]

- Step 1 (format: pnm) looks perfectly fine to me.
- Step 2 (format: ps) introduces a bit of left border.
- Step 3 (finally: pdf) introduces also a bit of right border.

So, something in step 2+3 must go wrong.
`-setpage` I introduced recently, brought a minor improvement. (before, I also suffered from top-margin).

*PS: If there's a „lever“ in any of these 3 steps to slightly increase contrast, let me know. ;)*

Answer (score 0):

Life is much better with 2 steps instead of 3, and using [graphicsmagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html) (which somehow was already installed on my Ubuntu-MATE 22, even if apparently not [standard install](https://distrowatch.com/table-mobile.php?distribution=ubuntumate&pkglist=true&version=22.04)) instead of the latter two above. There's even a `+contrast` that fits my needs. And it's all certainly not slower. Quality 35 reasonably suffices for archiving standard corresponding including photos and some fine print \o/.

```bash
scanimage -p --resolution 300 --mode Color --format=pnm -x 210 -y 297  \
| gm convert -compress JPEG -quality 35 +contrast pnm:- "$fname"
```